# Best way for cross platform client storage?

Tags: cookies, local-storage, client-side, indexeddb, client-side-data

I need a cross platform way to store data on the client without using cookies, because a token is being saved clientside which should not be sent to the server on each request.

Requirements

- old browser (IE6+) have to be supported
- has to be working on mobile devices (in webviews) as well

Comment: IE6 _and no cookies?_ You've got to be joking.

Comment: Can't you just use different fallback mechanism? for example ie6 requires flash or just use userdata (64KB per domain, xml based). if you have localstorage use that, all other cases use a modern browser :)

Comment: Hi David, any update? did you find something useful not mentioned here?

Comment: @Robesz I went with https://github.com/wojodesign/local-storage-js for now and can't complain so far. WebViews in Android and iOS are happy with it and even the old IEs are support with the fallback.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store data on the client without cookies. You could pass the session ID in the URL. As an example with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php but that's the best you can get.

I don't see a problem supporting IE6. Using 'progressive enhancement' you can provide a very basic site to older mobiles, IE6/7 and other crap. Then, layer on the more advanced stuff to the devices that can handle it. I don't test in IE6, but I'm 99% my sites work in it.

Comment: I would have expected something like PersistJS. Session IDs are no solution for my project.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [JayData ItemStore API](http://jaydata.org/blog/the-itemstore-api-101), there is a fallback mechanism while detecting the available local storage technologies. The priority order is WebSQL, IndexedDB, HTML5 localStorage. The bad piece of news that you need a HTML5 browser.

Disclaimer: I'm member of the development team of the open-source JayData library